# Grouping over multiple items in List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of dictionaries like below:

```
var result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Europe"}, {"Country", "Italy"}, {"Population", "10"} },
        new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "RSA"}, {"Population", "20"} },
        new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "RSA"}, {"Population", "30"} },
        new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "Nigeria"}, {"Population", "40"} },
    };
```

I would like to group by CONTINENT first, then group by COUNTRY and then within the result calculate a sum of POPULATION field, so in the example above:

- GROUP_1: Europe, Italy => Sum: 10
- GROUP_2: Africa, RSA => Sum: 20 + 30 = 50
- GROUP_3: Africa, Nigeria=> Sum: 40

I can do this with nested grouping, like below:

```
var resultGroupedByContinent = result.GroupBy(o => o["Continent"]);

foreach (var continent in resultGroupedByContinent )
{
   var resultPerCountry = resultGroupedByContinent.GroupBy(o => o["Country"]);

   foreach(country in resultPerCountry)
   {
      CalcualteSum
   }
}
```

Is there any better way of implementing this, making better use of grouping, LINQ ?

In the real case scenario I will be dealing with:

- a list that has a total number of few million items (result.Count()=few million)
- each dictionary 70 key-values
- 4 level of grouping (Continent -> Country -> 3rd level -> 4th level)

I just want to add that List<Dictionary<string, string>> can be replaced with a different data structure, basically as a source I am getting following JSON, and then I am using json deserialiser:

```
{
  "header": [ "Continent", "Country", "Population" ],
  "errors": [],
  "rows": [
    [ "Europe", "Italy", "10" ],
    [ "Africa", "RSA", "20" ],
    [ "Africa", "RSA", "30" ],
    [ "Africa", "Nigeria", "40" ]]
}
```

I will be getting such JSON with few million rows every 8 seconds, so that my cap for calculation time.

Comment: You are using a `string, string` dictionary to store `string, int`? You are going to run into performance issues here - is this really what the data looks like? What does `CalculateSum` do - is this psuedocode or have you tried this? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Lists of dictionaries are a really bad idea, as you're pretty unflexible on their datatype (unless you use the pretty ungeneric `object`). Maintaining this is hard. Instead you should consider to create some classes with that represent your structure: e.g. a `continent` has a list of `country`. Then you can also simplify your issue to something like `GroupBy(x => { x.Continent, x.Country }`.

Comment: Whenn the data grouping is done  what happening then, displayng it to some ui, writing it to some kind of databse, ...? Maybe you schould consider to filtering the data request. It's generally possible, but it looks like you need a different approach

Comment: @Jack please let us know, if any of the answers helped you any how

Answer (score 0):

If you have this `Dictionary<string, string>` only, I would convert them to an defined object first and then group by like this

```
    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
        {
            Country = dict["Country"];
            Continent = dict["Continent"];
            Population = int.Parse(dict["Population"]);
        }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }

--------------------------------------------------

            var result = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>
            {
                new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Europe"}, {"Country", "Italy"}, {"Population", "10"} },
                new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "RSA"}, {"Population", "20"} },
                new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "RSA"}, {"Population", "30"} },
                new Dictionary<string, string> { {"Continent", "Africa"}, {"Country", "Nigeria"}, {"Population", "40"} },
            };
            var mapped = result.Select(x => new MyObject(x)).ToList();
            var sum = mapped.GroupBy(x => new { x.Continent, x.Country }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Population));
```